# Proving inequality regarding arc length in Apostol's book

Tags: real-analysis, functions, bounded-variation

If P={$t_0,t_1,...,t_m$} is a partition of [a,b] prove that the following inequality holds.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}|f_k(t_i)-f_k(t_{i-1})|≤\sum_{i=1}^{m}||f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})||≤\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|f_j(t_i)-f_j(t_{i-1})|$$

where $f=(f_1,...,f_n)$. I managed to prove the left side of the proof but the other side cannot be solved. This is from Apostol's book page 135. Would really appreciate some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

$\big(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|f_{j}(t_{i})-f_{j}(t_{i-1})|\big)^{2}$

$=\sum_{j=1}^{n}|f_{j}(t_{i})-f_{j-1}(t_{i-1})|^{2}+\sum_{j\neq k}|f_{j}(t_{i})-f_{j}(t_{i-1})||f_{k}(t_{i})-f_{k}(t_{i-1})|$

$\ge\sum_{j=1}^{n}|f_{j}(t_{i})-f_{j}(t_{i-1})|^{2}=\|f(t_{i})-f(t_{i-1})\|^{2}$

for each $i=1,...,m$.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the inequality on the right simply by repeated application of the triangle inequality. The norm of a sum is less than or equal to the sum of the norms.